# How does parquet determine which encoding to use?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, parquet

**Context:**

- I have two identical datasets (say Left and Right) with 112 parquet files in each dataset.
- These parquet files were created using Hive, by converting delimited flat files.
- The process used to create the delimited flat files files is slightly different between left and right processes.
- I noticed a significant size difference between both datasets, even though the content in them is exactly the same. Left dataset is 400GB and Right dataset is 420GB.
- When I checked the Parquet schema using parquet-tools, I noticed different encoding was used for left and right datasets as shown (for one column) below:

**Left:**

```
column_a:  INT64 SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:4 SZ:5179987/6161135/1.19 VC:770100 ENC:PLAIN,RLE,BIT_PACKED
```

**Right:**

```
column_a:  INT64 SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:4 SZ:3040269/5671813/1.87 VC:782499 ENC:BIT_PACKED,PLAIN,RLE,PLAIN_DICTIONARY
```

**My Question:**

How does parquet determine what encoding type to use and what could have made parquet choose different encoding? Is it something we can control using a Hive / Spark config?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the mailing list message [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/parquet-dev/202003.mbox/%3CCAN%2BnMxS5O9-N7jeTU01bVkTRLRb9RT8ncjKdoEFoSaTp5VihZw%40mail.gmail.com%3E) with reply [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/parquet-dev/202003.mbox/%3cCAAhnZP4EmuRh7q+nALBfj69xVNA93OaGXU9RNOt-P=LTdGbqxg@mail.gmail.com%3e) has the best answer that I'm aware of. In short, you can't directly control the encoding that Parquet uses for any given column. There are some things that may help to improve it a bit, like specifying that you wish to write a Parquet Version 2 file rather than a Parquet Version 1 file, but that's not precise control. There may be something that can be done, but it would probably involve diving deep into the internals of a Parquet implementation.

Comment: this PR might be useful: https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/pull/342
alongside this jira:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-601

Answer (score 0):

The only writer that I found until now that allows you to define encoding for each column is the [Arrow Parquet Writer](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/formats.html#_CPPv4N7parquet16WriterPropertiesE). I do not found  way in the ParquetWriter API in the Java repository.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Rust's parquet writing library also allows you to specify column level encoding